# Split comma separated string to rows

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split

could you please solve the problem
write a query

input table `t1`

```
sno|sdata
123|abc123,abc456,bcd789
123|def1011,xyz123
```

I want this output

```
sno|sdata
123|abc123
123|abc456
123|bcd789
123|def1011
123|xyz123
```

please give idea to resolve the query as early as possible

Comment: Please, properly format your question. Also, show us what have you tried to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

Classic, more or less.

```
SQL> with test (sno, sdata) as
  2  (select 123, 'abc123,abc456,bcd789' from dual union
  3   select 123, 'def1011,xyz123' from dual
  4  )
  5  select
  6    sno,
  7    regexp_substr(sdata, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) sdata
  8  from test,
  9       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                           connect by level <= regexp_count(sdata, ',') + 1
 11                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

       SNO SDATA
---------- --------------------
       123 abc123
       123 abc456
       123 bcd789
       123 def1011
       123 xyz123

SQL>
```

**[EDIT, to show what happens if ...]**

... you omit lines 9 - 11.

Basically, COLUMN_VALUE references LEVEL (from line 9). If you rewrite it so that query doesn't use any of these, you'd get duplicates:

```
SQL> with test (sno, sdata) as
  2      (select 123, 'abc123,abc456,bcd789' from dual union
  3       select 123, 'def1011,xyz123' from dual
  4      )
  5      select
  6        sno,
  7        regexp_substr(sdata, '[^,]+', 1, level) sdata
  8      from test
  9      connect by level <= regexp_count(sdata, ',') + 1
 10      order by 1, 2;

       SNO SDATA
---------- --------------------
       123 abc123
       123 abc456
       123 abc456
       123 bcd789
       123 bcd789
       123 bcd789
       123 bcd789
       123 def1011
       123 xyz123
       123 xyz123

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

One way to avoid them is to use DISTINCT (which would do the job, but that's wrong), or use syntax I showed you in the first answer to your question.

Comment: I edited my message and added another example; have a look.

Comment: Time for the New Coke vs Classic ;) https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:41:17396416505176:::41:P41_ID:134700645804442772077199957899092885467 #18c